# OleDB provider not registered on hosted build agent in Visual Studio Team Services (was VS Online)

Tags: c#, continuous-integration, oledb, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm trying to get continuous integration up and running on one of my projects, and I'm running into an issue with testing.

My program uses an OleDB connection to read the contents of an Excel spreadsheet and writes relevant information to a csv file.

When I use the agent download to run the agent locally, it works fine, all of my tests pass and therefore so does the build, however, keeping my laptop running all the time is not feasible. When I use the hosted agent, during one of my tests, I get an InvalidOperationException with the message "The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine"

So my question is, is there a way to get OleDB on the hosted agent? Or perhaps a different way to do what I need to do that will be compatible with the hosted agent and testing?

Comment: You need to mock the external component using a mocking agent, like [moq](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Moq/)

Comment: Thank you, I'll look into that

Comment: There isn't any way to get OleDB on hosted build agent for now, you can submit a feature request on VSTS User Voice page: https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services?query=data%20provider.

Comment: @RobertWoods I'm running into the same issue, how did you solve that in the end?

Comment: @harveyAJ it was a bit long-winded, but I got an Azure virtual machine, installed the necessary software to use OleDb and used that to run the builds on

Comment: OK I think I see what you mean... In VSTS, I just need to create a custom "private" build agent that runs on that VM. You should probably post this as an answer 0:)

Comment: Yep, sorry, perhaps was explained a bit unclearly but that's exactly what I did. And I will do when I have time to do a write up. :)